# Measuring the current or the power

Tags: power-management

Is there a way to measure the electric current or power of the whole computer or its components using software? Voltage can be measured, and I am wondering why not with the current/power.

Comment: Is it a standard PC or something like a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Standard IBM or Intel compatible computer.

Comment: The only way to do this is with additional hardware. If you're lucky, you might be able to find a power supply with a current feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voltage can only be measured because most modern machines have *hardware* built-in that can do so; the software simply talks to the hardware over e.g. I2C and reads the values from it. No equivalent hardware for measuring current is in modern computers.